# Can we show Between date parameters displayed like below scenario

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

In my report contain FromDate and Todate Parameters,

but i need to display as drop down list below screen
[image]

When user clicks today it displays as today data,select IsBetween data displays as between data,

select this month displays as This month data  like that needed.

Can anyone explain me How can i achieve this above type scenario in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to pass the selected date description to your dataset query and have the appropriate dates calculated there before running the select statement. So the query would look something like this:

```
declare @StartDate date
declare @EndDate date
if @Date = 'Today'
BEGIN
  @StartDate = GETDATE()
  @EndDate = GETDATE()
END

SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE Date between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

And you would have to make sure you are passing the value of the Date parameter to the dataset like this:

[image]